# Cannot import local plugin in Grails 2.3.11

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I cannot import a local plugin inside my app whith these conventions:

```
grails.plugin.location.MyPlugin= '../MyPlugin'
```

or

```
grails.plugin.location.'MyPlugin' = '../MyPlugin'
```

or

```
grails.plugin.location.'MyPlugin' = 'c:/prj/MyPlugin'
```

or

```
grails.plugin.location.'MyPlugin' = 'c:\\prj\\MyPlugin'
```

With or without thise inside plugin conf.

```
    //compile ":myplugin:0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

The result is :

|Running Grails application

```
Error |
WARNING: Inline plugins for [MyPlugin] cannot be read due to error: ivy pattern must be absolute: 
    C:\Users\Luigi\.m2\repository
  /[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).pom (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: Try to use full path of your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (My home path it's '/home', and the plugin is 'urlrewrite')

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy

//use a copy of urlrewrite fixed in enviroment PRODUCCTION because, the repo don't have a functional version for grails 2.5.0
if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
    grails.plugin.location.urlrewrite = '/home/sam/Repositorios/BTask/Programacion/BTask/src/plugins/urlrewrite-0.1'
}

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...
```